# Switch from Compare Files in Visual Studio to normal file view

Tags: visual-studio

When I compare a file with its unmodified version in Visual Studio from Team Viewer, the Compare Files view is opened. The head version of the file is displayed on the left, the working copy on the right.

Is there a way (preferably a keyboard shortcut) to quickly switch from the Diff viewer to the normal file view of the working copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way I have found is using the following shortcut:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> to Sync Solution Explorer with active Document
And then simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it.

Comment: That's a nice workaround. On my setup the shortcut to find the current file in the Solution Explorer is ALT+SHIFT+L.

Comment: Just realized that the ALT+SHIFT+L is a ReSharper shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The best I have found is to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>[file_name]</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In my 2017 version of Visual Studio will bring up the "Open File" pop up window in the directory of the file you are currently looking at. You'll then need to retype part of the file name in order for Windows to suggest files for you to open.

I don't think it's quite what you wanted but at least you can do it without having to resort to using your mouse!

Note that you don't necessarily need to type the whole of the filename in as you can use the <kbd>down</kbd> key to toggle through suggestions offered.

Answer (score 0):

This combination works for me:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open `Solution Explorer` on respective file
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the file